# Extensions of valuations

Tags: number-theory, valuation-theory

I'm trying to understand how a valuation $v$ of a field $K$ extends to an algebraic extension $L$. In chapter 8 of his book ANT, Neukirch first chooses a $K$-embedding $\tau : L \longrightarrow \bar{K}_v$ where $\bar{K}_v$ denotes an algebraic closure of the completion of $K$ wrt $v$. He then defines a $K$-embedding $w=\bar{v} \circ \tau$ which is an extension of the valuation to $L$ and then considers the completion $L_w$. $\tau$ is clearly continuous wrt this valuation.

If $L/K$ is infinite, the localisation $L_w$ is defined to be the union $\bigcup_iL_{iw}$ of the completions $L_{iw}$ of all the finite subextensions $L_i/K$ of $L/K$.

I have two questions:

1) How does $\tau$ extend *uniquely* to a continous $K$-embedding $\tau : L_w \longrightarrow \bar{K}_v$ in the case that $L/K$ is finite?

2) If $L/K$ is infinite, is the above union a field? Also how does $\tau$ extend uniquely in this case?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: For (2, I think the union is an inductive limit, hence explaining your douubts, as long as (1 is proved. For (1, I cannot understand what the question is: we are extending $\nu$ , right? Also the paragragh explaining the construction of the extension does not specify the unicity. And, as far as I am concerned, there should be no unicity at all, else there would be no theory of ramifications. The last but not the least, what is your field $K$? A local or a global field? Regards.

Comment: We are trying to extend $\tau$ which is the $K$-embedding of $L$ into $\bar{K}_v$ as defined above to a continuous $K$-embedding of the completion of $L$ into the same field. Neukirch describes this embedding when $L/K$ is finite. But he also claims that this is unique which I can't quite understand. Here, K is just a valued field and v is a valuation which can be both archimedean and non-archimedean. Thanks